# Drupal search results filter, similar to drupal.org's search results page

Tags: drupal, search, filtering

Pretty new to drupal and I want to create a search results page that includes a filter, just like the one used on drupal.org (http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/test).

I've looked around for a module to do this, but haven't been able to locate one. Perhaps I'm not searching for the correct terms, but I've not had any luck.

Incase it matters, I have many nodes of content that are attached to a taxonomy of terms called "Tags" - I'd like to have the filter update the list of results based on the user selecting which "terms" to remove.

How are you accomplishing this?
TIA!

Edit:

Throwing in my install instructions for future travels:

- Goto the following website: https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/job/Solr-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/checkout/solr/dist/
  And find the nightly (Today’s date) build and download it.
- Expand and rename the downloaded folder as “apache-solr-nightly”. This should NOT live in your webroot.
- Download the zip here: http://solr-php-client.googlecode.com/files/SolrPhpClient.r22.2009-11-09.zip and unzip the file.
- Download the zip here: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/apachesolr-6.x-1.2.zip (Or the most current 6.x version) and unzip the file.
- Copy the schema.xml from the apachesolr-6.x-1.2/ that was just unzipped to the apache-solr-nightly/example/solr/conf
- Copy the solrconfig.xml from apachesolr-6.x.1.2/ to apache-solr-nightly/example/solr/conf
- Edit the solrconfig.xml and include the following line as a child of

> ```
> &lt;luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_40&lt;/luceneMatchVersion>
> ```

- Search for and comment out the following lines

  > <queryResponseWriter name="xslt"
  >   class="org.apache.solr.request.XSLTResponseWriter">
  >         <int
  >   name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5
  >   </queryResponseWriter>
- Change to the apache-solr-nightly/example directory and execute the solr jar
  java -jar start.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drupal.org uses [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) (together with Apache Solr, of course).

Comment: Ok, thanks, going to take a peak that now. I'll report back my findings.

Comment: Thanks again, having trouble w/the install but I Think this is was I need.